# TortoiseSVN repository browser kills the apache process

Tags: apache-2.2, tortoisesvn, svn, collabnet

After migrating the **CollabNet SVN server** to **Windows Server 2012** (Apache/2.2.26 (Win32) - SVN/1.8.5) the **TortoiseSVN repository browser** (TortoiseSVN 1.7.13) kills the Apache process on the server when I open a folder which contains more than 1000 files.

Repo browser error message:

> PROPFIND of '/svn/...': Could not read chunk size: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

On the server the apache service is crashed with this log entry:

> [crit] Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.

No more related entries in the log file (`httpd\logs\error.log`) or event viewer. The crash happens immediately, not a timeout issue. I can checkout / display the folder via web browser without crashing the server.

Any ideas? Should I increase some limits in the apache configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an **out-of-memory** issue and **not** related to TortoiseSVN repository browser. The svn command killed the Apache process too:

> svn ls --depth=infinity -v http://...

The command increases the **virtual memory usage** of the httpd process up to **1.7 GB** and crash the service. I will install the 64bit version of the svn server and talk to the developer to decrease the numbers of generated files in one folder.